# Getting the current transaction ID with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible with MySQL 5.5 to get the current transaction ID? Something like...

```
BEGIN;
SELECT CURRENT_XID(); -- foo
...
SELECT CURRENT_XID(); -- also foo
ROLLBACK;

SELECT CURRENT_XID(); -- NOT foo
```

The actual value isn't important, as long as I can get some unique identifier that will always return the same value throughout the same transaction.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bad solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CURRENT_XID() RETURNS VARCHAR(18)
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX 
            WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID());
END
```

1. Returns `NULL` if your only doing read only operations inside of a transaction.
2. Most importantly the `INNODB_TRX` is not synchronised with the transactions. So if you call `CURRENT_XID()` immediately after ending the transaction you will get a value back, but then wait a second and run it against and you will get `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Is there a way in mysql to "block" until this table is updated? (I'm doing this progrmatically and wish to not just do a time.sleep(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303079/how-do-i-determine-if-i-have-uncommitted-writes-in-a-mysql-transaction

Comment: Are you trying to check if there are outstanding transactions without interrupting the database or do you wish to put the database in to a state of readonly for a short time?

Comment: The former (check if outstanding transactions)

Comment: I don't believe there is a super reliable method for this, apart from looking at the innodb status and parsing the text.

Answer (score 3):

Have a gander at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-innodb-trx-table.html

There is no simple function to return that information but you could issues a special query look for it in that table and fetch the transaction_id

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX` returns `0`

Comment: It seems that the transaction is only registered in `INNODB_TRX` when the transaction is using non-readonly SQL commands. Bit annoying, but this should work...

Comment: Did you start a transaction first?

Comment: Ya, its less than graceful.

Comment: A transaction is implied if you do not explicitly use `BEGIN`, or at least it should be. I don't trust MySQL to do anything competently.

Answer (score 1):

When using MySQL or MariaDB, you can execute the following SQL query to get the current transaction id:

```
SELECT tx.trx_id
FROM information_schema.innodb_trx tx
WHERE tx.trx_mysql_thread_id = connection_id()
```

The [`innodb_trx`](https://vladmihalcea.com/current-database-transaction-id/) view in the information_schema catalog provides information about the currently running database transactions. Since there can be multiple transactions running in our system, we need to filter the transaction rows by matching the session or database connection identifier with the currently running session.

Note that, starting with MySQL 5.6, only read-write transactions will get a transaction identifier.

Because assigning a transaction id has a given overhead, read-only transactions skip this process. This read-only transaction optimization works the same way in MariaDB, meaning that a transaction id is only assigned for read-write transactions only.