# How do I determine if I have uncommitted writes in a MySQL transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm working with a very complex codebase and wish to do some introspection of how it works with MySQL.  (Note that I'm using InnoDB).

Specifically, in a method I'm writing, I wish to determine if there are any outstanding (non-committed) writes in its open db connection.

Is there any MySQL command - or other means - to detect if there are uncommitted writes? (or phrased another way, determine if COMMIT will make no modifications).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting question. I don't think there is a definite way to determine if issuing commit will or will not make a difference in the session you are running.

You can see transactions with `show innodb status` or [show engine innodb status](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-engine.html) but I don't think you can issue commit on those transactions.

`INNODB_TRX` table in information_schema will show currently executing transations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-trx-table.html and again there's not much you can do to force-commit them. You can roll them back by killing the associated process.

If you are running a transaction using [START TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) in a stored procedure, you can handle commit and rollback manually. You can even [set autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) to 0 to control when to rollback and when to commit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Doing SELECT TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID() does exactly what I want. (props to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620966/mysql-5-5-getting-the-current-transaction-id).  However, that table doesn't appear to be instantly updated when I do an insert; it appears to take ~100 ms in my tests.  I'm *fine* with the delay, but I don't trust an arbitrary sleep. Is there a mysql command that blocks until this table is syncronized?

Comment: I don't really know that deep of MySQL internals. You might have to dig into its source code to figure that out. Source code is on GitHub.

Comment: Followed-up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318846/how-do-i-synchronize-the-innodb-trx-table