# How do I synchronize the INNODB_TRX table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

This is a follow-up to [How do I determine if I have uncommitted writes in a MySQL transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303079/how-do-i-determine-if-i-have-uncommitted-writes-in-a-mysql-transaction)

I wish to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX to obtain information about the current transaction I'm in, e.g. with:

```
SELECT TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

However, I'm finding that the INNODB_TRX table is not synchronized with my transaction.  e.g. If I perform an insert() operation within a transaction it may take 100ms until the INNODB_TRX table contains the transaction_id.  The unpredictable delay makes it unreliable to use this in my production code.

Is there any command/method to either force-synchronize the table or block until it is synchronized?

Comment: Please elaborate on _why_ you want to do that.  It seems like you should simply issue a `COMMIT` and not worry about whether there are any pending writes.

Comment: The original question explains it; I'm debugging an existing code-base.

Comment: So, you have two threads?  And one might be in the middle of writing?  And the other wants to discover that?

Comment: No, it's a single-threaded environment in a complex code base.  Code maintains an open transaction while it runs.  When my method is code, I wish to detect (for debugging/assertion purposes) if writes have previously happened.